# Joda parseDateTime() returns future date

Tags: java, jodatime, date-parsing

parseDateTime() consistently returns a date about 23 days in the future. My local is Spain, so I'm UTC+2. Does anyone know why it would be doing this? I'm probably making an obvious mistake.

I'm using Joda 2.2 and JavaSE 1.7.

```
public class JodaTest {
private static final String INPUT_DATE = "Monday, 03 Jun 2013 20:54:20 -0700";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, ee MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z");

    DateTime dt = dtf.parseDateTime(INPUT_DATE);
    displayResults(dt);
    dt = new DateTime();
    displayResults(dt);
}

public static void displayResults(DateTime dt) {
    System.out.println("parsedDate: " + dt.toString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z");
```

As `dd` is for "[Day in month](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)".